# How to fix screen orientation to default (either potrit or landscape) for my whole PhoneGap app

Tags: html, cordova

I have created an app using phonegap. I have installed that app in my mobile. Can anyone explain me to how to rotate my app screen based on the mobile position?

My Config.xml file:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.mydomain.login_form" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
        <name>LoginForm</name>
        <description>
            A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
        </description>
        <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
            Apache Cordova Team
        </author>
        <content src="sample.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />

        <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
        <plugin name="net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation" spec="1.3.1" source="pgb"></plugin>
        <feature name="Whitelist">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Geolocation">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Geolocation" />
        </feature>
        <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
        <feature name="Compass">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.deviceorientation.CompassListener" />
        </feature>   
    </widget>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no any minor spelling mistake in your config file as you have wrote `potrit` instead of `portrait` here ?

Comment: I added my config.xml file. please check it whether is there any mistake in that file.

Comment: Thanks I got the answer by placing the below code in android.manifest file

Comment: <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

Answer (score 1):

You can set orientation preference into `config.xml` file

```
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />        
<!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
```

or

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

or

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

You can check other all config related settings here in [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml) link

Comment: Can you share you config code here in your question

Comment: Thanks I got the output by adding the following code in android.manifest file. <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" **android:screenOrientation="sensor" **android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">